# Way to Prevent Inadvertently Re-Sorting Email in Outlook 2003 by Accidental Click on Column Title

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

My mother is having trouble using Outlook (she is currently using 2003 version):

- It is set up to sort emails by date, descending (most recent email message received) first.
- However, she sometimes inadvertently clicks a column title (other than [date]"Received") in the header bar (such as "From" or "Subject") and then her inbox ends up being sorted other than by most recent date received, which frustrates and confuses her, as it is always done inadvertently by accident.

I have researched and looked, but am not able to find a way to "disable" inbox sorting by [mistakenly] clicking another column title in the header bar, so I am at a loss as to how to find a permanent solution for this problem.

I would not mind purchasing or downloading a third party program, or Outlook "Plug-in" that would solve this problem, but after lots of research on the net, I am not able to find anything that looks like it would help,

If someone would please advise me what they think would be the best solution, or "workaround" for this issue, we would really appreciate it.

Comment: You could just explain to her what's happening, and how to fix it by purposely clicking on column headings.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sorry. The only "workaround" I see is to reset all views each time Outlook starts: add /cleanviews command line switch to Outlook shortcut. Then she'll just need to restart Outlook each time she feels something went wrong.